# Mapping SQL NUMERIC[10,0] to java type

Tags: java, sql, regex, jdbc, sybase

I need to map `NUMERIC[10,0]` parameter type of a sybase stored procedure to a java type.

What would be this type?

Also, if you can help me define a regular expression for this `NUMERIC[10,0]` type I'll be greatful.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit, we have an edit history that allows us to see changes. In sometimes adding clarification is appreciated, but in this case your use of `numeric[0,10]` was obviously in error.

Comment: ok, Thanks. I really didn;t know if to leave the original and add an edit, or to edit the fault text as you did eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) as [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is to short to map all possible values. Have a look at `MAX_VALUE` of both types.

Comment: thanks. Doesn't the [0,10] talks about precision and scale? I really did not understood it? If so, should not it be float or double? Edit: Oh! My mistake! It was Numeric(10,0). The opposite is not logical :) So, scale is 0, so it can be an integer or a long. Thanks Again!

Comment: Oops, you are right. My mistake, sorry. I updated my answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again

Comment: Great, I rolled back to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@Column(name="x", columnDefinition="decimal", precision=10, scale=0)
private double x;
```